# Chicago-style citations of CJK documents (e.g. American Oriental Society): Name order; transcribed/translated titles

Tags: biblatex, cjk, chicago-style

Is there a way to produce Chicago-style citations of material written in Chinese, Japanese, for an English-language paper using biblatex-chicago?

I want to produce a citation that looks like:

> Li Wuwei 李无未, *Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi* 日本汉语音韵学史 (History of the study of Chinese phonology in Japan) (Beijing: Shangwu yinshuguan, 2011)

Right now, I'm able to produce a reference that looks like this using biblatex-chicago:

> Li Wuwei [李无未], *Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi,* 日本汉语音韵学史 [History of the study of Chinese phonology in Japan] (Beijing: Shangwu yinshuguan, 2011)

My .bib entry looks like:

```
@book{Liwuwei2011,
Author = {{Li Wuwei}}, %Author as institution not individual
nameaddon = {李无未},
Publisher = {Shangwu yinshuguan},
address = {Beijing},
Title = {Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi},
titleaddon = {日本汉语音韵学史},
usere = {History of the study of Chinese phonology in Japan},
Year = {2011}}
```

The problem is not the square brackets around the Chinese name and title, but

(1) the fact that the name now is not parsed as a name (if it were, it would be listed in the footnote as "Wuwei Li," and in the final bibliography as "Li, Wuwei," which is incorrect), but treated as one word. This means I cannot make the style cite the reference simply as

> Li, *Riben*

but only

> Li Wuwei, *Riben*

in subsequent citations. Dominic Yu (http://blyt.net/blog/2009/11/bibtex-and-chinese-names.html) kindly showed me how to solve this with bibtex. I wonder if there is a solution for biblatex-chicago?

The second problem is:

(2) The comma

> *Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi,* 日本汉语音韵学史

between the transcribed title and the original title. Is there a way I can get rid of that in the reference?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Next to the author field, you have the remark `Author as institution not individual`. Have you tried setting the field's value to `{Li, Wuwei}` (instead of `{{Li Wuwei}}`)? I'm afraid I don't have the required fonts and hence can't check out directly if this suggestion might help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I write the name as {Li, Wuwei}, it will be "Wuwei Li" in the footnote, and "Li, Wuwei" in the bibliography. However, convention has it that the name should be "Li Wuwei" in both footnote and bibliography, and, possibly "Li" in short, subsequent citations.

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. It appears that @Audrey's answer -- which provides a new method for rendering a person's name, besides the Western/default and "institution as individual" ways -- is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: [moewe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320738/34699) seems to have a quite promising and elegant solution to your first question, as well as insights to your second one, with `biblatex 3.5+` and `biber 2.6`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For problem (1), the `nameaddon` field can hold the CJK name for only a single author. This approach is no good for works by multiple authors and name lists in other fields, such as `editor`. One way around this is to reserve the name affix for the CJK name:

```
author = {Li, 李无未, Wuwei and Keane, Michael}
```

and modify the name formatting directives. This is somewhat awkward and you'll have to characterize "real" name affixes in order to properly format names like "Robert Griffin III" and "Lon Chaney Junior". A rudimentary `\ifnameaffix` test is used in the example below.

For problem (2), using the `titleaddon` field for the CJK title is probably the way to go for `biblatex-chicago` styles. Punctuation between the title and the title add-on is tangled up in a bunch of different formats, drivers and macros. One possible way out is to use `\nopunct` in the title formatting directives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
% Sets uniquelist=minyear and uniquename=minfull
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

% List of name affixes excluding Roman numerals
\forcsvlist{\listadd\nameaffixlist}{Junior,Senior}

\newcommand{\ifnameaffix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifrmnum{#1}} or test {\ifinlist{#1}{\nameaffixlist}} }}

% Based on definitions from biblatex.def    
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
       \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \or
       \ifuseprefix
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
     \or
       \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \fi}%
    {\ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{0}%
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{}{}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first/first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
        \ifblank{#3#5}
          {}
          {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro*{name:cjk}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#3}}}

% Based on definitions from biblatex-chicago cbx    
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}{}{\mkbibquote{#1}}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usere}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{zhaos,
  title={A Nation-State by Construction: Dynamics of Modern Chinese Nationalism},
  author={Zhao, Suisheng},
  isbn={9780804750011},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Stanford University Press}}
@article{zhaoj,
  author = {Zhao, 赵杰, Jie},
  title = {Qingdai Manwen de wenzi tese ji yinyun, yinbian tedian},
  titleaddon = {清代满文的文字特色及音韵、音变特点},
  usere = {Scriptual specificities of Manchu writing in the Qing period
           and characteristics of phonology and sound change},
  shorttitle = {Manwen de wenzi tese},
  journal = {Manzu yanjiu},
  volume = {102},
  number = {1},
  date = {2011},
  pages = {7--12}}
@book{li,
  author = {Li, 李无未, Wuwei and Brown, Junior, Bob and Doe, III, John},
  publisher = {Shangwu yinshuguan},
  address = {Beijing},
  title = {Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi},
  titleaddon = {日本汉语音韵学史},
  usere = {History of the study of Chinese phonology in Japan},
  date = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcite{li,zhaos,zhaoj} \\
\citeauthor{li,zhaos,zhaoj} \\
\fullcite{li,zhaos,zhaoj}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few notes:

- CJK names are not responsive to `firstinits`, but it is straightforward to make them so.
- Name disambiguation only considers the first and last parts of a person's name, not the affix. This is convenient for handling two ambiguous CJK names, but perhaps not ideal for ambiguities between CJK and non-CJK names (see the example).
- The name affix approach redefines generic formatting directives from `biblatex.def`. So it should work for a variety of styles.
- The formatting changes to handle the title add-on approach are very specific to `biblatex-chicago`. They have little use in other styles.

Comment: This looks great thank you so much! I will try it out immediately; but, where do I put the second string of code? Not in the document preamble?

Comment: Oh I also got it to work by putting it at the end of the preamble, so I deleted my comment before I saw this. Thank you so much, the reference produced looks perfect, this will be very helpful for anybody working in East Asian history/literature.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, the citations are working very well. I just noticed one problem though. In the bibliography, the types inbook, incollection (but not bookinbook), and article, there is still a full stop between the title field (enclosed in quotation marks), and the journal/book/series title. Do you think there's a way around this?

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Thanks again, this is invaluable.

Comment: @Mårten No problem. You may have noticed that the `notes` style sets an extraneous comma after the leading reversed name in a two-person list: "Last1, First1, and First2 Last2". If that isn't by-design you might want to contact the `biblatex-chicago` author.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I assume the Chicago Manual of Style wants it that way. I tried to use the "author-date" option in biblatex-chicago (instead of "notes"), which led to the CJK names not parsing correctly. Is there a way to use the author-date option with the CJK solution you developed?

Comment: @Mårten If I use `authordate` instead of `notes` in the above example, I don't see any issues other than having to use the `date` field instead of `year` in the `bib` file.

Comment: Hmm. References such as this one does not parse correctly for me: @article{Zhao2011Wenzi, author = {Zhao, 赵杰, Jie}, title = {Qingdai Manwen de wenzi tese ji yinyun, yinbian tedian}, titleaddon = {清代满文的文字特色及音韵、音变特点}, usere = {Scriptual specificities of Manchu writing in the Qing period and characteristics of phonology and sound change}, shorttitle = {Manwen de wenzi tese}, journal = {Manzu yanjiu}, volume = {102}, number = {1}, date = {2011}, pages = {7–12} } I get this: J. Zhao 赵. 2011 Do you know why? Sorry for the strange spacing in this comment.

Comment: @Mårten Adding that entry to the above document and loading with the notes option, I get the correct output. Your output produces initials. I can only guess that you're using another document/configuration that changes the name format.

Comment: @Mårten I forgot to mention that there are [plans](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/biblatex/index.php?title=Multi-script_support) to better support multilingual documents. Probably not in the very near future, but it will likely be the next major feature introduced into biblatex+biber.

Comment: That is great news! I think many people in Asian studies would benefit from it. When it happens, is it likely that I will have to reformat all the biblatex entries in my database?

Comment: @Mårten With the name affix hack, definitely. For further details, Philip Kime would be the best person to ask. You could contact him directly or post at the [github repo](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: Sorry, I've been looking around for Philip Kime's email but I can't find it online? Could you post it here alternatively email it to me at msoderbl@princeton.edu ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking about this, but as I tried to use the author-date style with this patch I noticed that it cannot handle CJK names very well when there are two names with identical romanization but different Chinese characters. Is there a way to always make CJK names appear as `[Family name] [Given name] [Date]` whenever the default `[Family name] [Date]` is ambiguous (leaving out the CJK characters)?

Comment: @Mårten Please open up a new question providing some details. I won't be quick to answer it, but perhaps someone else will.

Comment: @Mårten Nevermind. I think the fix is easy. I'll post an edit in a minute. We should clean up this comment trail at some point.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to fix this. It works perfectly. I assure you that I make use of this patch literally every day.

Comment: I've noticed a problem with the author-date style. Even though I have too citations from 2 different publications by the same author that are both from the same year, the biblatex doesn't print the letter following the year to disambiguate the citations (e.g. 2008a and 2008b---both appear as 2008, but the link points to two different citations). Do you know how to fix this, or would you prefer that I ask a new question while referring to this one? In any case, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mårten The above code doesn't interfere with year labels. I can't reproduce this issue on my end, so you'll need to provide some sample `bib` entries. Feel free to update your existing question to do that.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm sorry to assume that it was your script that was the problem. It turns out the problem is the option cmsdate=both. I've posted a question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115866/no-disambiguation-of-same-year-same-author-citations-in-biblatex-chicago-author

Comment: Sorry to get back to this old question. I'm still using your patch daily and I just noticed a problem. As far as I can tell, the name disambiguation does not work with two CJK names that differ in #3 (e.g., one entry with {Zhao, 趙歲升, Suisheng} and one with {Zhao, 赵杰, Jie}). I've tried to edit the patch myself but I don't understand enough to make it work. Do you prefer that I post this issue as a separate question, referring back to this one?

Comment: Re my previous comment: I posted it as a separate question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233053/chicago-style-citations-of-cjk-documents-2

Comment: @Mårten Since the last name Zhao is non-unique, I'd expect the `uniquename` counter for those entries to be non-zero. This doesn't seem to be the case. I've posted an issue at the biblatex github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Being an east-asianist myself, I came across your (Mårten’s) guide and this question. Thank you for both.

While it doesn’t use biblatex-chicago, the following still is a very simple yet working solution for the problem of inserting entries with Asian names.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Sans}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@book{zhangdainianruhe1994,
        title = {Ruhe yanjiu guoxue},
        titleaddon = {如何研究国学},
        volume = {3},
        rights = {山东大学文史哲编辑部},
        issn = {0511-4721},
        journaltitle = {文史哲},
        author = {Zhang~Dainian, 张岱年},
        date = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}% : instead of . after name
\begin{document}
Hello world.\footcite[p. 32]{zhangdainianruhe1994}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the footnote, only the Western name is stated. In the bibliography, First the Western name and then the Chinese name is stated. This is achieved by simply securing the space between Zhang and Dainian: Zhang~Dainian, and putting the characters as the first name, behind the comma.

Done like this, you can easily write Western names as well by simply using the regular space instead of ~.
I use xelatex instead of pdflatex, hence polyglossia instead of babel.