# How to include a Chinese paper in reference via bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, unicode

When including the following entry in my `ref.bib`

```
@article{chen2012,
  title={基于电无级变速器的内燃机最优控制策略及整车能量管理},
  author={陈骁 and 黄声华 and 万山明 and 庞珽},
  journal={电工技术学报},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={133--138},
  year={2012}
}
```

it shows up as

[image]

I'm using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\bibentry{chen2012}

is used for XXX study.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No version of `bibtex` is capable of dealing with a UTF-8 encoded `.bib` file. For this you need to use `biber` and `biblatex`.  See [Chicago-style citations in CJK documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66825/2693) for an example.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Provided a suitable CJK font is loaded, wouldn't LuaLaTeX and/or XeLaTeX (together with BibTeX) be able to handle this typesetting task? I.e., are biblatex and biber absolutely required? Naturally, the value of the `author` field might have to be augemented by some `\noopsort` instruction to help BibTeX in the proper sorting of the entry.

Comment: @Alan Munn  How to typeset it using Biblatex then?

Comment: @Mico No.  To quote Philipp Lehman "Make it absolutely clear that BibTeX can't handle UTF-8. This is probably the second most common misunderstanding when it comes to BibTeX. There is no way around this restriction. BibTeX can't deal with multi-byte encodings. It's just not going to work."  [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/comp.text.tex/4LC-xODb-LU/1Bd5UZOMNM4J).

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks for providing this information, I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @user1664196 I'm sorry I don't have a working example that I can show you, and a simple example doesn't work. However, the `caspervector` style for `biblatex` may do what you need, but the documentation is all in Chinese, which I don't know.  If you have a recently updated TeX distribution, it should be included; if not, you can get it from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-caspervector). It would also be helpful to edit your question to ask specifically about using `biblatex` for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here an example which uses CJK. The compilation is shown by the rules of `arara`.

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{chen2012,
  title={基于电无级变速器的内燃机最优控制策略及整车能量管理},
  author={陈骁 and 黄声华 and 万山明 and 庞珽},
  journal={电工技术学报},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={133--138},
  year={2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=99,maxalphanames=5]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\verb+\cite{chen2012}+\cite{chen2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]