# Document Bibliographies with CJK and Pandoc

Tags: biblatex, xetex, cjk, pandoc

Very new to LaTeX and only limited exposure via pandoc,

I'm converting markdown English article that contains Japanese and Korean bibliography sources to PDF via LaTeX using pandoc, which allows the use of a LaTeX template. I very often use CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) bibliography sources (`bibtex` files exported from Zotero and modified for CJK needs) which contain extra information such as the author and title name in the original characters, romanization and translation.

To get this to work in my workflow, I was delighted to find this question/answer, which was extremely helpful: [Chicago-style citations of CJK documents (e.g. American Oriental Society): Name order; transcribed/translated titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/chicago-style-citations-of-cjk-documents-e-g-american-oriental-society-name/66825#66825)

However, I'm not able to replicate the results shown there, with the sample provided there, using pandoc.

The main problem is that the translation of the title, the "usere" data in the `bibtex` bibliography, does not appear in the final conversion with pandoc.

To see what I'm seeing:

Sample Markdown file `test.md`:

```
This is a test.[@zhaoj, 22] Another test.[@li, 14]

# References
```

Sample Bibtex file `bib.bib` (taken from the StackExchange post):

```
@article{zhaoj,
  author = {Zhao, 赵杰, Jie},
  title = {Qingdai Manwen de wenzi tese ji yinyun, yinbian tedian},
  titleaddon = {清代满文的文字特色及音韵、音变特点},
  usere = {Scriptual specificities of Manchu writing in the Qing period
           and characteristics of phonology and sound change},
  shorttitle = {Manwen de wenzi tese},
  journal = {Manzu yanjiu},
  volume = {102},
  number = {1},
  date = {2011},
  pages = {7--12}}
@book{li,
  author = {Li, 李无未, Wuwei and Brown, Junior, Bob and Doe, III, John},
  publisher = {Shangwu yinshuguan},
  address = {Beijing},
  title = {Riben Hanyu yinyun xue shi},
  titleaddon = {日本汉语音韵学史},
  usere = {History of the study of Chinese phonology in Japan},
  date = {2011}}
```

Sample TeX template `template.tex` for pandoc essentially just using the solution provided in the above link:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Kai}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\nameaffixlist}{Junior,Senior}


\newcommand{\ifnameaffix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifrmnum{#1}} or test {\ifinlist{#1}{\nameaffixlist}} }}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
       \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \or
       \ifuseprefix
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
     \or
       \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \fi}%
    {\ifnumequal{\value{uniquename}}{0}%
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{}{}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first/first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
        \ifblank{#3#5}
          {}
          {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro*{name:cjk}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#3}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}{}{\mkbibquote{#1}}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usere}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

And finally, the pandoc command used to make it all work:

```
pandoc --template=template.tex --latex-engine=xelatex test.md --biblio=bib.bib -o test.pdf
```

The result is almost there but

1. missing the "usere" translation of the titles,
2. unlike the output in the link above, surrounds both the romanized and original Chinese with quotation marks, and
3. appears to add an extra comma here and there:

   [pandoc conversion output http://huginn.net/t/latex-output.png](http://huginn.net/t/latex-output.png)

For those of us out there writing academic articles that use Japanese, Chinese, and Korean sources, help with this would be really appreciated. I'd love to compile the suggestions made in the link above and answers here in a post to provide a tutorial for future users who have a similar situation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I will be ready to test the new multiscript branch of biblatex in the not too distant future and it seems you would be an ideal candidate. It should allow you to have multiple variants if the same field in the .bib so you don't have to resort to `usere` etc.

Comment: @KonradLawson You might have better luck getting this sorted out at the pandoc DL. I'm not sure pandoc can fully support biblatex, let alone biblatex-chicago and the upcoming multiscript features of biblatex 3.0.

Comment: Would look forward to trying it @PLK, and Audrey, perhaps you are right. It was worth a try.

Comment: Someone took out the thanks in an edit, hope it is alright I put it back in, though I understand this issue is something of a controversy in the SO community. I don't have rep to upvote answers as was suggested in the edit so a short respectful thanks should be a tiny step towards keeping things human.

Comment: Konrad our policy here is that we usually don't have thanks on posts.  One standard message we have is: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I have had similar Problems as I am studying Chinese and Oriental Studies and lastly resorted to writing my own biblatex style to conform with the university’s requirements. A somewhat hacky solution, yet it works the way intended—so far. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJjK.jpg) for how it looks. Note the difference between works published in German or English with a Chinese parallel title and works originally published in Chinese with a translated title.