# biblatex-chicago \fullcite

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to get full, bibliography-style citations in line using biblatex-chicago with `biber` as the backend (I'm using XelaTeX; biblatex 2.9a; biblatex-chicago 2014.1.31). I understand this is normally done with the `\fullcite` command, but when I enter this command, I get the exact same output as I do when I replace `\fullcite` with `\cite`, i.e., a citation that puts parentheses around the publisher, address, and date. (Actually, there is one difference between `\fullcite` and `\cite` in my document: `\fullcite` prevents the reference from being abbreviated if it has appeared previously in the document.) When I use `\printbibliography`, the citations appear correctly, in bibliography format.

I don't know if it matters, but I am using `\documentclass{article}` (nothing changes if I change the class to, say, `{book}`). I am also using some unusual code to format CJK bibliography entries, copied from a post by Audrey here at stackexchange (for which I am eternally grateful, by the way! [Chicago-style citations of CJK documents (e.g. American Oriental Society): Name order; transcribed/translated titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/chicago-style-citations-of-cjk-documents-e-g-american-oriental-society-name/66825#66825)). I do not understand this code, and so don't know whether it might be responsible for the behavior of \fullcite. A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{C:/dissertate/Dissertation.bib}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Contextual, TeX}]{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=0.9]{仿宋}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt


\forcsvlist{\listadd\nameaffixlist}{Junior,Senior}

\newcommand{\ifnameaffix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifrmnum{#1}} or test {\ifinlist{#1}{\nameaffixlist}} }}

% Based on definitions from biblatex.def

\newbibmacro*{name:cjk}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#3}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\iffirstinits
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first/first-last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifblank{#7}} or test {\ifnameaffix{#7}} }
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
        \ifblank{#3#5}
          {}
          {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
       {\iffirstinits
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{#1}{#3}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% Based on definitions from biblatex-chicago's notes.cbx

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitleaddon}{}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}{}{\mkbibquote{#1}}%
  \iffieldundef{titleaddon}{\isdot}{\nopunct}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{usere}{\mkbibparens{#1}}


\begin{document}

\fullcite{ChengShankai}
\fullcite{Dudbridge}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Edit: Apologies for not including the bibliographic reference. Both CJK and normal references included here.

```
    @book{ChengShankai,
    author = {Cheng, 成善楷, Shankai},
    title = {Du shi jianji},
    titleaddon = {杜诗笺记},
    publisher = {BaShu shudian},
    address = {Chengdu},
    year = {1989}
}

@book{Dudbridge,
   author = {Dudbridge, Glen},
   title = {Lost Books of Medieval China} ,
   publisher = {The British Library},
   address = {London},
   year = {2000},
}
```

The result is as follows. As you can see, it is in citation, rather than bibliography, style:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you've run-up against is the fact that biblatex-chicago repurposes the `\fullcite` command so that it no longer displays the entry using the same driver as the bibliography, but rather to ensure that the full entry is cited instead of the short form or ibid. The Manual pretty much discourages what you're doing.

However, its fairly straight-forward to produce the required results. Below, I've just created a new cite command `\fullcite*` which exhibits the required behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
% new code
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%\bibsentence
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \toggletrue{cms@fullnote}%
    \togglefalse{cms@shortnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:full*}
   \usebibmacro{cite:save}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}

\newbibmacro*{cite:full*}{%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}\frenchspacing}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fullcite{aristotle:physics}

\fullcite*{aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For concision, I've included the new definitions in the preamble with `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` to ensure it works as expected. Ideally, though, these commands should go in `biblatex.cfg`.

[image: Screenshot showing the results]

Answer (score 3):

Your minimal example is not usable: The bib entry is missing and you are using uncommon fonts. It is unclear what you get and what you expect to get instead. Also it would be easy for you to test if the additional definitions are responsable for your problem (I doubt it): simply comment them and try out what happens.

If I compile this example with pdflatex + biber:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{angenendt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get with biblatex v2.9a and biblatex-chicago 2013/10/29 the expected result:

[image]

Comment: I've added the requested information in the question above. You are right that it isn't the code per se that is causing the problem; when I comment it out, the problem persists. But maybe it is somehow the bibliography that I've written to work with the code? As for the fonts, I am using MikTeX on Windows, and these are system fonts. For my work I can't use pdflatex; too much Chinese text everywhere.