# Biblatex and Beamer and IEEE problems

Tags: beamer, biblatex, errors, citing, ieee-style

I am not entirely sure if this is unique to the `beamer` class, but I am running into a plethora of errors with a variety of `biblatex` commands when I use the `ieee` style (I am relatively sure that it's a feature of the `ieee` style because many (including `authoryear-comp`) seem to work fine).

Some commands I can't seem to get working with the aforementioned combination of `ieee`, and `beamer` `biblatex`:

- `\cite{}` works intermittently (depending on my theme)
- adding `\printbibliography` breaks the success of `cite` when it was part of a compatible theme ***
- `parencite` compile fails ***
- `fullcite` compile fails ***
- there was a redefinition of some commands in the answer to this question:  [biblatex-chicago \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196479/biblatex-chicago-fullcite) that I tried to implement because `fullcite` was one of the first commands I recognized wasn't working under the `ieee` style and i thought the custom chicago style might have had a similar underlying problem, but I don't think thats the case.

*** only worked with  `authoryear-comp`, `beamer`, and `biblatex`

Skeleton MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
        url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/510},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{doi}}


\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}% remove article icon:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/removing-document-icons-from-a-bibtex-bibliography-in-beamer

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    Text \cite{A01}

    %Text \fullcite{A01}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This question is likely the first in what will be a series of questions as I endeavor to create a `biblatex` solution to implement custom compressed-full inline text citation in a beamer presentation.

Comment: The only problem I had with your MWE was the one described in [MacTeX 2016 somehow broke a bbx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315532/35864). The easiest solution is to load a language package. You can not use the `\DeclareFieldFormat` solutions described there. You can disable title casing with `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{#1}`.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your comment! If I understand you right, the style I chose to use has some internally declared (titlecase & sentencecase) rules that are conflicting `biblatex`'s internal (default) operations and need to be explicitly overwritten or provided?

Comment: The style uses the macro `\MakeSentenceCase*`. In `biblatex` 3.4 that macro has a slight problem if you don't explicitly set a document language (this bug will be fixed in the upcoming version 3.5). You can thus either (1) declare a document language by loading `babel`/`polyglossia` (this will enable the macro again), or (2) get rid of `\MakeSentenceCase*` with the two lines I proposed above (leaving you of course with non-sentence-cased fields).

Comment: @moewe Thanks again!  I should have been a little more explicit, your linked question provided that description about the `babel`/`polyglossia` (I tend to prefer `polyglossia`) which I found very informative, what had me thinking it was a style specific property, was the fact that some of the built in styles (`authoryear-comp` to be specific) worked fine.

Comment: Indeed, the standard styles do not use `\MakeSentenceCase*` by default (still `\MakeSentenceCase*` is defined in the `biblatex` core). So with them the problem does not occur. Some custom styles such as `biblatex-ieee` and the one used in the other question use `\MakeSentenceCase*`, and then the problem creeps up. Would you say your question is a duplicate of the other one?

Comment: @moewe I know that the solution is a duplicate, but I still haven't been able to match up the errors in my MWE and the linked question.  I only get beamer frame errors on the common undefined control sequences message to the linked question.  I have some more changes I want to try out next chance I get, but at the moment, the linked question shares so few keywords that even knowing what the answer was, I still couldn't get to it from google.  Because this is a package problem that already has a planned fix I will probably remove the question once I verify it's useless.

Comment: With your MWE I get `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \bbl@main@language l.39 \end{frame}`. Which tells you that `\bbl@main@language` is the undefined culprit, but that TeX only noticed it in or around line 39 in `\end{frame}` (the problem occurred in `\printbibliography` (l. 37), really). After applying one of the fixes, the problem goes away for me. `\bbl@main@language` is an internal command that is undefined if you don't load a language package, here it is the macro `\MakeSentenceCase*` that tries to call the macro even though it is undefined, a guard against that has been added.

Comment: I agree that the questions don't have many matching keywords, but if you consider only the error message you get (which is what I strongly suggest you include in your question), it is fairly obvious for anyone coming across this question that they are duplicates. Even if we are to close your question as a duplicate it will remain searchable, so I don't see a problem there.

Comment: For a bit more detail: `biblatex-ieee` defines an internal macro called `\bbx@colon@search`, amongst other things that macro calls `\MakeSentenceCase*` which has the bug described in the other question. There are two instances where the internal colon search macros are used `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\bbx@colon@search{#1}}\DeclareFieldFormat{sentencecase}{\bbx@colon@search{#1}}`. As soon as you start to print titles, the problem occurs.

Comment: @Jessse, could you elaborate?  Scrolling through the answers, this isn't even close.  I am voting to close my own question because moewe own answer and discussion above is an identical problem/answer.  I don't see any relationship to various tools to compile a local document.  I disagree that adding this link will benefit the duplicate link.