# Biblatex problem with multiple authors and Asian names where last name comes first

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

**Edit:**

I realised it has something to do with the fact that I referenced Vo earlier on in a separate paper (Vo 2008). Now the in-text citations work fine if I refer to Vo as "Vo, Tri Tranh", but the bibliography now reads

[image]

Which is still not ideal since it should be "Vo, Tri Tranh" following on from "Bui, Truong Giang".

**Original:**

New Latex user. I'm trying to reference Bui and Vo (2007), and their full names are Bui Truong Giang and Vo Tri Tranh.

I know that bibtex uses "and" as a separator and "," to distinguish between first and last names, therefore I've formatted my bib entry as such

```
@article{BV:2007,
  title={Approach to Development Gaps in ASEAN: A Vietnamese Perspective},
  author={Bui, {Truong Giang} and Vo, {Tri Tranh} },
  journal={ASEAN Economic Bulletin},
  volume={24},
  number={1},
  pages={164--180},
  year={2001},
}
```

However, when I use \parencite or \textcite in my main file it comes out as (am aware there is a typo that was changed after I took the screenshot, it should read 2007 not 2001)

[image]

Where it works for Bui, but not for Vo.

Same issue in the referencing, so somehow it's just not going into the code right.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I just want the citation to come out as "(Bui and Vo 2007)", and preferably "Bui Truong Giang and Tri Tranh Vo (2007)." in the bibliography.

If it helps, my starting code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: The output of the bibliography is decided by the citation style you're using (APA, MLA, etc.). However you format your entries in your .bib file this will come out the same unless you change the citation style to one where all names are printed in the format "LastName, FirstName".

Comment: That makes sense, however, is there a reason why in my bibliography output Bui has a comma but Vo does not, even when they're both written in the same format {Bui, Truong Giang and Vo, Tri Tranh} in the .bib file?

Comment: I think it is because of the citation style (which is not the same as your .bib file formatting). If I have three authors: John Smith, Davy Jones, and Bob Ross, and in my .bib file they are {Smith, John}, {Jones, Davy}, and {Ross, Bob} it won't matter if the citation style used (e.g. "authoryear" with biblatex) has a rule that says "In the bibliography authors shall be listed as: Smith, John, Davy Jones and Bob Ross." It will come out that way in my bibliography unless I change citation styles. Unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: First of all: BibTeX's name implementation was (apparently) written with the Western name format, where the natural order is `<given name> <family name>`, but `<family>, <given>` is used for 'indexing' etc., in mind. `biblatex` inherits BibTeX's name format, but with Biber allows you to extend the format to allow for more precise treatment of names that don't follow these Western conventions.

Comment: Some examples are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287732/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425829/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390369/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585772/35864

Comment: The output you see is made more complicated by different factors: (1) As Plergux says, your style shows the first name in `<family>, <given>` and all subsequent names in `<given> <family>` order [that kind of makes sense, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534462/35864, but may look odd at first]. You can change this with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` or `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}`. (2) `biblatex` has a name disambiguation feature that adds name initials to the family name in the citations to avoid ambiguous names. ...

Comment: ... That is the cause of the "T." in "T. Vo", which would otherwise just have been "Vo". This feature can be turned off with `uniquename=false`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.