# CJK names and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, cjk, pinyin

CJK names still pose a problem in bibliographies using `biblatex`:
there is no built-in option to differentiate between the name in transcription and in CJK characters, which sometimes leads to constructs that are not adaptable like

```
author = {{Wang Li 王力}}
```

There’s a great solution written by the user [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) for the package `biblatex-chicago`:
[CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago author-date style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390369/cjk-bibliography-problem-biblatex-chicago-author-date-style)

It lets you specify names as shown below and will display them correctly in the footnote and the bibliography:

```
author = {family=Wang, given=Li, cjk=王力}
```

I’m not proficient enough myself, but could it be adapted to work with `biblatex`?

Comment: The name code should also work for standard `biblatex` styles. You just need to copy it and change `chicago-authordate.dbx` to `<name of the style you want to use>.dbx` (e.g. `authoryear.dbx`).

Comment: 93-nameparts.tex in the doc/latex/biblatex/examples folder contains also an example of the cjk name template.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for pointing that out, it works. Should I delete this question or do you want to make your comment an answer so it might help others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CJK code from [CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago author-date style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390369/35864) is largely based on what the `biblatex` example document `93-nameparts.tex` does ([`93-nameparts.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/93-nameparts.tex) and [`93-nameparts.dbx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/93-nameparts.dbx)). Indeed the code applies to formatting macros that are the same in `biblatex-chicago` and the `biblatex` standard styles, so

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\usepackage[fallback]{xeCJK}

\begin{filecontents*}{morenameparts-cjk.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{cjk-names.dbx}[2016/07/24 extended name format for biblatex]
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,cjk}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  datamodel=morenameparts-cjk,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate[cjk]{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{cjk}
  }
}

\DeclareUniquenameTemplate[cjk]{
  \namepart[base=true]{family}
  \namepart[disambiguation=full]{given}
  \namepart[disambiguation=full]{cjk}
}

\newbibmacro*{name:cjk}[3]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamecjk{#3}}}

\newbibmacro{labelname:western}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newbibmacro{labelname:cjk}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{uniquepart}{base}%
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\empty}
       {\empty}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{uniquepart}{given}%
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\empty}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartcjk}}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifuniquenametemplatename{cjk}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:cjk}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:western}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given}{%
  \ifsortingnamekeytemplatename{cjk}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartcjk}}
    {\ifgiveninits
        {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiven}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
  \ifsortingnamekeytemplatename{cjk}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartcjk}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family}{%
  \ifsortingnamekeytemplatename{cjk}
    {\usebibmacro{name:cjk}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartcjk}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
        {\ifgiveninits
           {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
             {\namepartfamily}
             {\namepartgiveni}
             {\namepartprefix}
             {\namepartsuffix}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
             {\namepartfamily}
             {\namepartgiven}
             {\namepartprefix}
             {\namepartsuffix}}
         \ifboolexpe{%
                     test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
                     and
                     test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
           {}
           {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
        {\ifgiveninits
          {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
             {\namepartfamily}
             {\namepartgiveni}
             {\namepartprefix}
             {\namepartsuffix}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
             {\namepartfamily}
             {\namepartgiven}
             {\namepartprefix}
             {\namepartsuffix}}}}
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{zhaos,
  title     = {A Nation-State by Construction},
  subtitle  = {Dynamics of Modern {Chinese} Nationalism},
  author    = {given=Suisheng, family=Zhao, cjk=趙歲升, nametemplates=cjk},
  year      = {2011},
  address   = {Stanford},
  publisher = {Stanford University Press},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{zhaos}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

should work.

(On my machine I can't get the CJK characters to show, but I'm not really familiar enough with `xeCJK` to debug this.)