# Specifying author pseudonyms in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I'm using BibLaTeX with following options:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

How do I correctly specify pseudonyms?

```
@misc{kent2016,
  author = {Clark "Superman" Kent},
  title = {Mindset of a Winner},
  year = {2016},
  url = {https://www.supermanhomepage.com/},
  urldate = {2019-03-14}
}
```

There is a [realauthor field](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-realauthor/documentation/biblatex-realauthor.pdf) but when I enable it with `bibstyle=realauthor`, it only changes the numeric reference style and does not help otherwise.

Comment: Could you maybe explain better what you are getting now and how it is wrong? Also please share a mwe for other users to compile and understand your problem `:)`

Comment: What is the expected output here? Would `Clark "Superman" Kent` be sorted under `S` for `Superman` or under `K` for `Kent`? What would `\textcite`/`\citeauthor` show? You may also want to include a short MWE that shows what you tried so far with `realauthor` and how it did not work for you.

Comment: @Superuser27 `bibstyle=realauthor` overwrites `style=numeric`. I guess `bibstyle` and `style` are the same option. There is nothing wrong, it's just a citation style that I'm not looking for.

Comment: @moewe `\citeauthor` prints Kent and  the entry is sorted under K in the references. I really don't have an expectation for the output. I want to know what the 'BibLatex way' of handling pseudonyms is, so that I can use it accordingly. Other than that, I could just leave the pseudonym in quotes as I did in the question.

Comment: I have never used the `realauthor` package, but from what I understand there is a serious limitation: It only works if a work has a single author. If there are multiple authors, it breaks. This was actually the reason I came up with my own solution. I originally had something similar with another name field, but to make it work with multiple authors, you have to use nameparts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of a `biblatex` standard solution for `pseudonyms`. Normally a name consists of the following four parts

- family (last) name
- given (first) name
- name suffix (Sr, Jr.)
- name prefix ("von part")

If you type in the name as `Clark "Superman" Kent` "Superman" will just be parsed as a second given name. For many intents and purposes that probably works alright, though the result with `giveninits` might be subpar.

---

It is possible to work out a more semantic solution with Biber's extensible name format.

The idea is to add a fifth name part, the `pseudonym`. It can be treated differently from all other name parts. In the example below the `pseudonym` is not used for sorting and it is only shown when the name is displayed in `given-fmaily` order.

See [Bibtex/Biber: how to cite an author using Ethiopian conventions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864) for another more involved application of the extended name format with more explanations. [CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320693/35864) and [Chicago-style citations of CJK documents #2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233053/35864) may also be interesting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% This defines a new data model
% that is necessary to make the new name part known to Biber.
% In a production environment one would put pseudonym.dbx where
% LaTeX can find it and would not use filecontents.
\begin{filecontents*}{pseudonym.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,pseudonym}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{kent2016,
  author  = {family=Kent, given=Clark, pseudonym=Superman},
  title   = {Mindset of a Winner},
  year    = {2016},
  url     = {https://www.supermanhomepage.com/},
  urldate = {2019-03-14}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber, datamodel=pseudonym]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


% use name:given-pseudonym-family instead of standard name:given-family 
% and add another argument {\namepartpseudonym} at the end
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-pseudonym-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}
      {\namepartpseudonym}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-pseudonym-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}
      {\namepartpseudonym}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newcommand*{\mkbibcompletenamegivenpseudonymfamily}[1]{#1}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamepseudonym}{\mkbibquote}

% Name formatting macro
% mostly copied from standard name:given-family
% but with the bits for #5 added
% {<family>}{<given>}{<prefix>}{<suffix>}{<pseudonym>}
\newbibmacro*{name:given-pseudonym-family}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#5#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#5#3#1}%
  \mkbibcompletenamegivenpseudonymfamily{%
    \ifdefvoid{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
    \ifdefvoid{#5}
      {}
      {\mkbibnamepseudonym{#5}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
    \ifdefvoid{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
       \ifprefchar
         {}
         {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
    \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
    \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,cicero,geer}

\textcite{kent2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is not spectacular

[image: Citation: "Kent [3]" Bibliography: [3] Clark “Superman” Kent. Mindset of a Winner. 2016. url: https://www.supermanhomepage.com/ (visited on 03/14/2019).]

Comment: Thanks! :-) I suppose this works with multiple authors e.g. `author = {{...}, {...}}`? Also, where do you define that double quotes are used? I can't find it in the code.

Comment: @mike Yes it does, that is one of the great advantages of using the extended name format over a separate field like `realauthor`. Try `author  = {Lois Lane and family=Kent, given=Clark, pseudonym=Superman and Emma Sigfridsson},`. The quotation marks are added with `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamepseudonym}{\mkbibquote}`, where `\mkbibnamepseudonym` is the analogue to `\mkbibnamefamily` for `pseudonym`.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented pseudonyms in my style `biblatex-fiwi`. I don't think any other style supports this. I try to briefly summarise what I did.

**BEWARE: THIS IS MESSY CODE, I AM SURE THIS COULD BE DONE IN A MUCH CLEANER WAY**

For declaring the name, I make the distinction between the pseudonym which is the name which is normally used on the book (or whatever document it is) and the real name. For this I introduce new name parts: `trueprefix,truefamily,truesuffix,truegiven`.

These have to be defined with `\DeclareDatamodelConstant`:

```
\DeclareDatamodelConstant[type=list]{nameparts}{prefix,family,suffix,given,trueprefix,truefamily,truesuffix,truegiven}
```

I then defined a test whether an entry actually has a pseudonym:

```
\newrobustcmd{\ifpseudo}[2]{%
\ifboolexpr{%
        ( not test {\ifdefvoid{\nameparttruefamily}} or not test
        {\ifdefvoid{\nameparttruegiven}})}%
        {#1}{#2}%
}
```

Now the definition of the name format has to be adapted:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}
      \ifpseudo%
        {\usebibmacro{name:true:family-given}
        {\nameparttruefamily}
        {\nameparttruegiveni}
        {\nameparttrueprefix}
        {\nameparttruesuffix}}
        {}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}%
      {\namepartprefix}%
      {\namepartsuffix}%
      \ifpseudo%
        {\usebibmacro{name:true:family-given}%
        {\nameparttruefamily}%
        {\nameparttruegiven}%
        {\nameparttrueprefix}%
        {\nameparttruesuffix}}%
        {}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Now we need the macro `name:true:family-given`:

```
\newbibmacro*{name:true:family-given}[4]{%
\addthinspace\bibopenbracket{=}%
  \ifuseprefix%
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
    \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnametrueprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}%
         {\mkbibnametrueprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       }%\ifpunctmark{'}{}{\addhighpenspace}}%
       \mkbibnametruefamily{#1}\isdot%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
        {}{\addcomma\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametruegiven{#2}\isdot}%
        \ifdefvoid{#4}
        {}{\addcomma\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametruesuffix{#4}\isdot}}%
            {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
            \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
    \mkbibnametruefamily{#1}\addspace\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}
        {}
        {\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametruesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \addcomma\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\addcomma}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametruegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametruesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
        \addspace\ifdefvoid{#3}
        {}
     {\addlowpenspace\mkbibnametrueprefix{#3}\isdot}}%
     \bibclosebracket
}
```

The actual entry for a name with a pseudonym looks like this:

```
@book{Blish.J:1973a,
    Address = {Chicago},
    Author = {given=William, family=Atheling, suffix=Jr., truefamily=Blish, truegiven=James},
    Edition = {2},
    Origdate = {1964},
    Publisher = {Advent Publishers},
    Subtitle = {Studies in Contemporary Magazine Science Fiction},
    Title = {The Issue at Hand},
    Year = {1973}}
```

The printed bibiliography looks like this with `biblatex-fiwi`:

[image]

Note that I only print the real name in the bibliography and not in the in-text citation

IME there can also be problems with BibTeX GUIs. `BibDesk` which I use to manage my bibliographic data has a hard time dealing with the unfamiliar name entries.

As I said: I am sure this can be done in a much neater way, but it works …

**EDIT** If you actually are going to use `biblatex-fiwi`, simply add the `true`nameparts to the name, the style will take care of the rest. But in its current form, the style is heavily geared toward German speaking humanities.