# bibliography in multiple languages (Chinese+Pinyin)

Tags: bibliographies, chinese

I'm from China. When I write paper in English I want the author's name in bibliography be displayed in `'English transcription' + 'Chinese Character'`. But I've encountered problem when do so, when there are multiple authors.

(I'm working on Win10 + TeXlive 2018 + Texmaker + Xelatex + Bibtex)

Below is my .bib file

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
﻿
@Article{Jacques2010,
  author         = {Jacques, Guillaume},
  title          = {The Tangut imperial title},
  journal        = {Central Asiatic Journal},
  year           = {2010},
  volume         = {54},
  number         = {1},
  pages          = {60-65},
  issn           = {0008-9192},
  endnotereftype = {Journal Article},
  shorttitle     = {The Tangut imperial title},
}

@Article{Sun2006,
  author   = {Sun, {Jackson T.-S. 孙天心}},
  title    = {Jiāróngyǔ dòngcí de pàishēng xíngtài 嘉戎语动词的派生形态 ({D}erivational morphology of verbs in {R}gyalrong)},
  journal  = {Minority Languages of China 民族语文},
  year     = {2006},
  number   = {4},
  pages    = {3-14},
  issn     = {0257-5779},
  abstract = {嘉戎语动词有丰富的形态变化,在语法体系中起到重要的作用。本文引举四大坝嘉戎语草登话与修梧话第一手语料,系统介绍嘉戎语改变词类、调整述语论元结构等二类主要动词派生形态。},
}

@Article{linluo03,
  author   = {Lín, {Yòujīng 林幼菁} and Luó, {Ěrwǔ 罗尔武}},
  title    = {Chábǎo jiāróngyǔ Dàzànghuà de qūxiàng qiánzhuì yǔ dòngcí cígàn de biànhuà 茶堡嘉戎语大藏话的趋向前缀与动词词干的变化 ({T}he directional prefixes and verb stem alternations in the {D}azang dialect of {J}aphug {R}gyalrong)},
  journal  = {Minority Languages of China 民族语文},
  year     = {2003},
  number   = {4},
  pages    = {19-29},
  abstract = {本文讨论嘉戎语组语言的趋向前缀和动词词干的变化在大藏话中的表现。趋向前缀在大藏话中参与了完成体、命令式、未完成体及间接示证完成体等动词形态的构成。标示趋向的有两套前缀。大藏话的词干交替多以变音交替的手段保留在少数开音节动词中。及物与不及物动词中的词干交替条件与古嘉戎语三个动词词干交替的格局相呼应。 },
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

And below is the .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=SimHei,ItalicFont=KaiTi,BoldItalicFont=LiSu]{SimSun}   
\usepackage{hyperref}   
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue,bookmarksopen=false,pdfstartview=FitH}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{authoryear,round,comma,aysep={\,},yysep={,},notesep={,}}  

\begin{document}
The 1st citation see \cite{Jacques2010}, and the 2nd see \cite{linluo03}, the 3rd see \cite{Sun2006}

\bibliographystyle{unified} %a style for linguistics journals
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

The output .pdf file will be like this
[image]

The third citation is exactly what I wanted `Sun, Jackson T.-S. 孙天心` since in the .bib file it is defined by `author = {Sun, {Jackson T.-S. 孙天心}}`. BUT, when it comes to multiple authors, it just won't work as I desired. The second author in the second citation displays as `Ěrwǔ 罗尔武 Luó`, while what I desired is `Ěrwǔ Luó 罗尔武`. How to fix this problem?

P.S. 
Since I write papers in English as well as Chinese, is there a flexible way that allows it to automatically change bibliography style depending on whether I'm writing in English or Chinese?

That is, When I write in English, Chinese references are displayed in the way I said above. When I Write in Chinese, Chinese references are displayed only in Chinese, without transcription. I think biblatex may do the job but I haven't tried it yet.

I saw a [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28010/how-to-create-multilingual-english-japanese-bibliographies-with-biblatex-bib?noredirect=1&lq=1) describing similar question, but it was in 2011 and complicated (it's a bit difficult for me to read long answers 'cause my English is not so good) . I wonder if there's an easier way to do this now.

Comment: Welcome to TEX S.E. ! Your PS is another question. You should post it as a separate question. `mlbibtex` would do what you want in this additional question btw.

Comment: I cannot compile your MWE because of missing fonts. This may be related to my older texlive distribution, but please check if the fonts you are using are available in texlive.

Comment: @sztruks Thanks for your comments. I've come up with a solution myself. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution and it works fine now.

I changed the author field in bibtex into: `author = {Lín, 林幼菁, Yòujīng and Luó, 罗尔武, Ěrwǔ},` The position which the chinese characters occupy is originally for Jr./Sr. in names.

Then the output changed into: `Lín, Yòujīng 林幼菁 & Ěrwǔ Luó, 罗尔武.`

The unified.bst I'm using defines a comma before Jr./Sr.. So I then revised my .bst file, replacing the comma with a blank. Then it perfectly became `Lín, Yòujīng 林幼菁 & Ěrwǔ Luó 罗尔武.` , exactly what I want.